# Can't access to POST parameters using expressJs with AngularJs POST Request

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, express, body-parser

I can't access to my post parameters when I'm doing post request with angular, here is my angular code :

```
var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/login',
                data: {
                    login: 'alex',
                    password: 'test'
                }
            })
            .success(function (res, status, headers) {
                if (res.token != 'undefined'){
                    user.token = res.token;
                    user.login = credentials.login;
                    user.userid = res.userid;
                    user.islogged = true;
                    $cookieStore.put("user", user);
                }
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

Here is my back-end code in my router file :

```
/************ API ******************/
app.post('/api/login', user.login);
```

And here is the code of my user controller

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {

console.log(req);

var user = {
    login: req.query.login,
    password: sha1(req.query.password)
};
...
}
```

I have nothing in req.query object otherwise if I make my request with Advanced REST Client plugin for chrome everything work fine.

Note: I'm using body-parser module to read parameters of my request.

Here is the github repository : https://github.com/alex3165/numeractive/tree/dev/node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enables the use of json parser

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Note: you have to install body-parser package, just open your terminal (command prompt in windows), chnage your directory to the root of your project and type the following

```
$ npm install body-parser --save
```